# How to draw two 3d graphs (one on top of another) in R using scatterplot?

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I'm sure this is a very simple problem, but somehow I can not find the answer. So in 2D if I want to display predictions on top actual values I do something like this:

```
plot(x, y, type = “l”, col = “green")
lines(x`, y`, type = “l”, col = "blue")
```

but I can not figure out how to do this in 3d (I’m using `scatterplot3d`)
I manage to display actual values

```
s3d<-scatterplot3d(x, y, z, color = “blue”, type = “l”, …)
s3d.coords <- s3d$xyz.convert(x,y,z)
D3_coord=cbind(s3d.coords$x,s3d.coords$y)
```

but how do I draw a graph for predicted values on top of that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are going for, but here is one option (notice the differing data structure as input to scatterplot3d - a vector rather than a matrix for `z`):

```
library(scatterplot3d)

n <- 10
x <- seq(-10,10,,n)
y <- seq(-10,10,,n)
grd <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
z <- matrix(2*grd$x^3 + 3*grd$y^2, length(x), length(y))
image(x, y, z, col=rainbow(100))
plot(x, y, type = "l", col = "green")

X <- grd$x
Y <- grd$y
Z <- 2*X^3 + 3*Y^2
s3d <- scatterplot3d(X, Y, Z, color = "blue", pch=20)
s3d.coords <- s3d$xyz.convert(X, Y, Z)
D3_coord=cbind(s3d.coords$x,s3d.coords$y)
lines(D3_coord, t="l", col=rgb(0,0,0,0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Why do we need a matrix for z?

Comment: You don't - it was only for illustration. The `scatterplot3d` function only requires 3 vectors (e.g. `X`, `Y`, and `Z`).

Comment: Could you please update your example so that two graphics have different color? if it's not too much trouble. Thanks